# fprint- Device already claimed (Ubuntu 18.04/Thinkpad X230)

Tags: usb, 18.04, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader, x230

I recently installed fprint with the intention of using it as a sign on method on my Thinkpad. However, it only seems to work on logon, and after this point it will return an error about it being claimed. I've tried to find any information from lsof or what have you but have had no luck.

Device information: Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:2020 Upek TouchChip Fingerprint Coprocessor (WBF advanced mode)

```
$sudo fprintd-verify
Using device /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
failed to claim device: Device was already claimed
```

Comment: I found that this article helped me.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/623929/fprintd-the-driver-encountered-a-protocol-error-with-the-device

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem just now, here's how I solved it:

1. Open the system monitor(make sure to set your view to all processes.)
2. Search for fprint/fprintd.
3. End/Kill the fprint process.
4. In a terminal run fprintd-verify.

That fixed it for me.

I think ending the process removed the previous claim on the scanner, allowing a new claim to be made.

Hope this helps, have a wonderful day!